# I'm not sure if my foreign key is working

Tags: php, html, sql, database, phpmyadmin

I've made a system where employees can send feedbacks.

Feedback form:
[image]

Now I have two tables in my database, tbl_feedback and employee:

tbl_feedback:
[image]

employee:
[image]

The employee_id in my tbl_feedback is a foreign key that references id in employee table.

My question is, is it really necessary to put Employee ID on my form for it to work? Because I noticed that when I remove Employee ID on the form, I get an error. Does that also mean I didn't set the employee_id column to a foreign key? properly?

Here's my insert feedback php code:

```js
<?php
require_once ('database.php');

if (isset($_POST['send'])) {

$employee_id = $_POST['employee_id'];
$full_name = $_POST['full_name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$website = ($_POST['website']);
$message = ($_POST['message']);

{
$database->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$insert_query = "INSERT INTO tbl_feedback (employee_id, full_name, email, website, message)
VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

$insert = $database->prepare($insert_query);
$insert->execute(array($employee_id, $full_name, $email, $website, $message));

echo "<script>alert('Successfully sent!'); window.location='feedback.php'</script>";
}
}
?>
```

Here's how I created tbl_feedback:

```html
CREATE TABLE tbl_feedback (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  employee_id int NOT NULL,
  full_name varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  email varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  website varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  message varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (employee_id) REFERENCES employee(id)
 );
```

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Do you mean the insert feedback php code? Or do you also need the query I used to create the table?

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Provided the php code and the query I used to create tbl_feedback

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Do you mean if I remove the employee_id from the php code?

Comment: You said `Because I noticed that when I remove Employee ID on the form, I get an error.` Im just asking where you took the employee_id from instead, when you did that

Comment: @PhilippMaurer Oh yeah I meant when I removed employee_id from the php code, I just get an error so I wanted to know if it's really necessary to put employee id on the form

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you remove the `employee` information from your feedback form, without getting the information from another source, you will defineately have a problem.

The foreign key constraint you added to your tables just makes sure, that there is not feedback entry in your table, that has no corresponding employee to map it with.

This means, that it does not magically maps the two tables with each other and makes sure that each feedback has a linked employee, but rather throws an error for each feedback entry that can not be linked to an employee, based on the given `id`. The errors you encountered are therefore actually proof, that your foreign key constraint works correctly.

So eventhough you have a foreign key constraint, you still have to manage the mapping in your code.

Comment: Yes, but it means that you still have to add the `employee_id` to your form or find another way to find out which employee filled out the form.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm not sure if I know what you mean about finding another way to find out which employee filled out the form tho

Comment: I do have an admin account where you can view the feedbacks. Is that what you meant? Sorry I didn't really catch that.

Comment: @AndreF I mean, that if you do not want `employee_id` to be part of the form, you must think about another way to get it. The session for example, if you have a login, or as GET parameter, if each employee gets a personalized link. I cannot tell you which ways there might be, because it depends on your porject. A discussion would be to bug to be discussed on this community.

Comment: I understand. Yeah I don't really want the employee id to be part of the form, at least I know there are other ways to get it done without the employee id. For the mean time I guess this would work out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If there is a Foreign Key in Table then table needs the key to be passed when inserting the data. It doesn't matter if you are passing via Form or getting your employee id from the database via PHP code.